# php - remove "code" param in facebook app URL

Tags: php, facebook, url, parameters

I have now finished my facebook app and it works, But, when a user first autherises to use the app, i then redirect them to http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ as given in the facebook documentation.

```
$app_id = "123456789";

$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/";

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=email,publish_stream";
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
if(empty($data["user_id"])){
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    echo "Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]."<br/>";
    // UPDATE CODE START
    // below code from facebook docs
    $app_secret = "asdfghjkl1234567890qwerty";
    $my_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/";

    session_start();
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
        $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
        . $_SESSION['state'];

        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }

    if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
        . $params['access_token'];

        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
        echo("Hello " . $user->name);
    } else {
        echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
    }
    // UPDATE CODE END
}
die();
```

The problem is that in the browser url it looks similar to the following:

http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?code=saydyab7da976dgas976gdas6gdas6gd06asgd86ags0d6g...etc

What is the "code" parameter and why is it there and how do i get rid of it?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use that `code` to get an access token. Until then, you have not yet finished the authentication process.

From the documentation, after you obtain that code, you need to send it to the Facebook Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

To summarize, Facebook OAuth authentication is a two step process, you have only done one of the steps.

Thanks!