# Remove ?state= from URL when user logs into Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my url show domain.com/?state=5a02… instead of just domain.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223716/why-does-my-url-show-domain-com-state-5a02-instead-of-just-domain-com)

I've asked this question previously but I was far too vague. When a user logs into my Facebook web application, the URL ends in both `?state=` and `&code=`. For example,

```
http://example.com/?state=asfsfs05sfd&code=afsafaf98790saf
```

How would I be able to remove that to give only `http://example.com`?

I've read this tutorial: [php - remove "code" param in facebook app URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012801/php-remove-code-param-in-facebook-app-url)

Is my authentication process incomplete?

Comment: Okay, sorry @CBroe. I will do next time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let it redirect to `domain.com`, but to `domain.com/finishfacebookauth.php?state=...`.

On the `finish` page you can do with state and code what you need to do (e.g. store them in your session or in a database, don't know whether and when you need them again), and then redirect to `domain.com`.

Comment: Ah that's a great idea thanks very much! Is that how the majority of Facebook web apps will do it?